# How to specify the source (git branch) of a conda build package

Tags: python, git, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I created a conda package that build successfully, and that I can install with conda. I am using [versioneer](https://github.com/python-versioneer/python-versioneer) to automatically generate the version number of my builds. My project is in a git repository with multiple branches.

My problem is that when I want to install the package, conda will install the last built version (no matter the branch), whereas I would like that it installs by default the last version of the branch Master.
My workaround is to manually specify the version number of the version I want.

Is there a way to generate a version number with versioneer that will make conda install in priority the last built version of the branch master? Alternatively, is there a way to specify conda the branch to get the latest build?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add more clarity to your question, like a step by step explanation of how do you proceed?

Comment: Hi, I have a Python project that I build as a conda package using `conda build conda.recipe`. The version number of the build is generated by versioneer. This yields a package with an increasing version number for each build. However, `conda install my_package` does not distinguish between builds coming from the branch master or an other branch (let's say develop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than varying the version, I'd suggest looking into encoding the branch info into either [the build string](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#build-number-and-string) or [the label/subdirectory](https://docs.anaconda.com/anacondaorg/glossary/#cloud-glossary-label). To me, these seem more semantically consistent with the situation.

### Build Variants

For the former, this could either be done explicitly by defining a build string that includes some jinja-templated variable coordinated with the Git branch, or automatically through variants defined in the `conda_build_config.yaml`. If you get this working, then installing a build from branch `foo` would go something like:

```bash
conda install my_package=*=*foo
```

I don't know a simple example of this, but the Conda Forge `blas-feedstock` uses [a `conda_build_config.yaml` to define the set of `blas_impl` options](https://github.com/conda-forge/blas-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml#L1), which is then used to [define build strings on the various outputs in `meta.yaml`](https://github.com/conda-forge/blas-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml#L57).

### Repository Labels

For the latter, I only know about Anaconda Cloud hosting (which you may not be using). In that case, one adds a label (subdir) with:

```bash
anaconda upload -l foo my_package.tar.gz
```

If you went this route, then installing a build from a branch `foo` would go something like:

```bash
conda install channel/foo::my_package
```

where "`channel`" is the channel to which you upload.

Comment: I think I'll go with the second option. Many thanks!